# Replace all non-unique values in NumPy array by value not in dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am dealing with large (masked) 2D NumPy arrays which originate from country wide raster datasets of 10 to 200 meter resolutions. The arrays are very large and can contain several millions of values.

I would like to perform the following operation on these kinds of arrays in the most efficient way possible:

```
in_array = numpy.array([[1,2,2],[4,4,6]])
out_array = uniqify(in_array)
print(out_array)
>>>
numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

or some other combination of numbers. It really does not matter the value, what I care about is that there are NO duplicate values throughout the array. Each cell value must be unique, and the magnitude of the cell must not matter.

This is one way of doing it, but I worry that it may seriously break down for large datasets:

```
def uniqify(array):
    count = 0
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            array[i][j]= count
            count = count+1
    return array


array = np.array([[100,2,3],[4,5,5,],[4,8,7]])
uniqified = uniqify(array)
print(uniqified)
```

I wonder if there are any ready-made, computationally efficient methods to do this without using nested `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple

```
  out_array = np.arange(in_array.size).reshape(in_array.shape)
```

Comment: could you extend this to a masked array?

Comment: If you don't care about the values, just use this method and then apply the same mask you have to out_array

Comment: I cannot simply modify the values in the original masked array? while preserving the mask itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but you can access the mask using
np.ma.getmask(in_array)

Comment: hmm, it seems theres no `np.ma.setdata(masked_array, new_data)`. I guess I have to construct a new masked array from the original mask and the new uniqified data

Answer (score 1):

You can modify an array in place by selecting all values via `[:]`:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,2],[4,4,6]])

A[:] = np.arange(A.size).reshape(A.shape)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```